# node.js cannot get nodemon to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

```
 [nodemon] 1.9.2
 [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
 [nodemon] watching: *.*
    [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
    events.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
```

seems like i cannot get nodemon to work keep on getting this error. also with the install of nodemon i am getting this error and also unable to solve it. on internet i cannot find a good sollution.

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or       higher
to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
 C:\Users\pfzwaan\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon ->         C:\Users\pfzwaan\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js
 C:\Users\pfzwaan\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

`-- nodemon@1.9.2

```
  npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /nodemon/chokidar/fsevents
```

:
      npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fseve
          nts@1.0.12

where should i update this one? Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 i am on a windows 7 i tried everything so i hoping someone can explain me how to get this to work!

Comment: `npm install -g nodemon` install once, use everywhere

Comment: I checked system variables one more time and found the cause of the problem: missing C:\Windows\System32\ variable. I added it and that solved my problem